# Click event in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How to know the id of current Html element when clicking on a Html element using plain JavaScript?

```
<div id="myId">
  <div>
    <h2>First Div</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Second Div</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to catch "myId" while I am clicking on the body of this div. That means I would like to get the ID of parent div when I click on `First Div` and `Second Div`.

My JS code is like below.

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
   alert(e.target.id)
}
```

Comment: Depends on how you register event handler. Post your JS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that in the following way:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('myId');
div.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log(this.getAttribute('id'))
});
```

```html
<div id="myId">
  <div>
    <h2>First Div</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Second Div</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You solution is working when I click on `Parent With id myId`. But I would like to click on `First Div` and `Second Div` and get the id of parent div. Thanks

Comment: This will attach the event handler on every div, including the div's surrounding the h2's.   You can target your selector by doing `querySelectorAll('div[id]');`

Comment: @abuabu  change selector to 'div[id]` as mentioned above, this will then prevent this event getting attached to the `div`'s without the id attribute.

Comment: @Mamun, you have now targeted a single element, `div[id]` will target any with any id attribute.  eg. If you edited the html now to have `<div id="myId2">`  It won't work for this one.

Comment: @abuabu, please notice the update in the answer where I have used `getElementById` instead of  `querySelector` which is most efficient in this case......thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`event.currentTarget` will be the dom element that the event is triggered by.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write a function:

```
function showid(elem) { 
    var id = elem.id
    console.log(id)
    alert(id)
}
```

And in your HTML code:

```
<div id="myId" onclick="showid(this)">
  <div>
    <h2>First Div</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Second Div</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this in vanilla JS, register an event handler on the document and retrieve the id of the clicked element:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    alert(e.srcElement.id);
});
```

```html
<p id="paragraph1">First Paragraph</p>

<button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
```